# Password not resetting on a database through an ASP.Net application

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

I am trying to reset a password to an employee number on a database through a ASP.Net application. The trouble is that it is not actually resetting the password on DB even though I am getting a confirmation message that the password has been reset.

Here is my current code

```
SqlConnection sqlcon = new SqlConnection();
SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
string empNo = "";

empNo = txtEmpNo.Text;
empReset = txtEmpNo.Text;
// sql statement to check if employee number exists in DB
SqlCommand check_User_Name = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_Login WHERE (Emp_ID = @user)", sqlcon);
check_User_Name.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", empNo);
int UserExist = (int)check_User_Name.ExecuteScalar();

if (UserExist > 0)
{
    //EmpNo exists
    sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("update tbl_Login set Emp_Pass=@Pass where Emp_ID=@EmpID", sqlcon);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID", empNo);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass", "1234");
    lblExists.Text = "Password reset!";
}// end if
else
{
    //EmpNo doesnt exist
    lblExists.Text = "Employee doesnt exists";
}//end else
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to execute your second statement in the if:

```
if (UserExist > 0)
{
    //EmpNo exists
    sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("update tbl_Login set Emp_Pass=@Pass where Emp_ID=@EmpID", sqlcon);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID", empNo);
    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pass", "1234");
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // <- execute update
    lblExists.Text = "Password reset!";
}// e
```

Answer (score 1):

you missed

```
sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Nikheel Rajman my answer is same his answer but i did before him , so why his answer marked as a right answer !